# Рассылка писем по базе (НЕ СПАМ) php

Tags: php, smtp, email

Добрый день!

Есть база с пользователями (зарегистрированными на нашем сайте), их около 10к. Это некий сервис работы, после создания вакансии должны отправляться уведомления тем, кто подписан на рассылку вакансий, а это почти 6к адресов. Ранее, когда база была небольшая, то отправлял функцией mail php. Но с увеличением количества адресов письма начали становиться в огромную очередь (если рассылка идет, например, по 10 вакансиям), приходят с задержкой, нагружают сервер (VDS timeweb).

У кого есть опыт - поделитесь как решали данную проблему? Можно ли каким-то образом настроить отправку писем через smtp яндекса или т.п.?

Comment: ИМХО при таких объемах разумнее использовать специализированные сервисы для рассылок. Посмотрите в сторону SendGrid, mailgun, Amazon SES и т.п.

Comment: Да всё верно, необходимо использовать сервисы рассылки писем.
MailChimp как пример